# ReactJs - How to prevent users from tampering/modifying equality checks in the client side code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently building a sample social network application with ReactJs 16. As a part of my application, I allow users to login and add posts. User can add friends too.

Each user has his own profile page. On his own profile page, a logged in user can see his own posts ( he can also edit/delete his own posts).

A user is also able to view his/her friend's profile page.
However, on the friend's profile page, logged in user can only see the posts and cannot edit/delete his friend's post.

The way I am achieving this behaviour is by checking that logged-in user id is same as the id of the post creator. Only if the id's match, I show the user the edit/delete option on the post.
I have created a `Profile` component which is rendered when user clicks `Profile Page`. This component is reused for showing both logged-in user and friend's profile page.

I want to know if there is any better alternative to achieve the above behaviour? The reason I am not happy with the way I have implemented this is because I am doing the above id equality check on the front-end (i.e client side code) and it can be easily tampered by the user.
I am aware that by using uglification, I would be able to make my code hard to reverse engineer but it wont be impossible for any determined chap.

Hence, I am interested in knowing is there a more robust and secure way to achieve this behaviour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fact that the user can modify the client-side code shouldn't really matter, as the server-side should be designed around "don't trust the client".

Even if the end-user couldn't see or modify the JS, they could still modify the network requests being sent to the server anyway (e.g. changing the post ID in the delete request to their friend's).

Your server should prevent users from modifying or deleting things they shouldn't be able to, such as other user's posts, and it should return an error to the front-end which informs the user that they were not allowed to perform the requested action.

This is the safest way to implement it, as it ensures that the user can't do things they shouldn't be able to, even if they modify the UI.

Comment: I think that makes sense. I am choosing your answer as accepted. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

your best way is actually limit the behavior is in the server (back end) using authorization (maybe DB entry of owningUserId ?).

even if the user will not find the code in the front end, he could imitate a POST request to the server with the friend's id and ask to delete/edit whatever he wants.

But in this specific case, i would probably use props to determine if the user viewing the post is the owner\friend and use 2 different components to show the data (but this is not the best practice).

Comment: I have accepted @Jack's answer as accepted. But like to thank you as well.